# CSS Computed width different from specified

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As shown in this [bin](https://jsbin.com/segufusuho/1/edit?html,css,js,output) the width specified for the preview button is 120 px while the rendered width is always 132 px (on different screens).

```css
.btn-grey{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f1f3f6;
    border: 1px solid #d7d9e1;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff inset;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #838AAB;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
            <div style="display: flex; width: 60%; justify-content: center;">
                <input name="preview" class="btn-grey" value="Preview" style="flex-basis: 120px; width: 120px; height: 35px;max-width: 120px; max-height: 35px; margin : 5px 5px 5px 5px " title="preview"/>
                <input name="load" class="btn-grey" type="submit" value="Load " style="width: 120px; height: 35px;max-width: 120px; max-height: 35px;margin : 5px 5px 5px 5px "/>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box;` in your button style

This will make sure that width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin.

For more information about `box-sizing` check the following link 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to add `box-sizing: border-box` to the `input`.

The reason is that an elements `box-sizing` defaults to `content-box`, which mean its `padding`/`border` by default adds to its set `width`, and with `box-sizing: border-box` it gets computed within it.

Src: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box-3/#width-and-height

*As a note, another option would be to use [CSS Calc()](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation), like this:*

- `width: calc(wanted_width - left/right_padding - left/right_border)`

Stack snippet

```css
input {
  box-sizing:border-box
}

.btn-grey{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f1f3f6;
    border: 1px solid #d7d9e1;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff inset;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #838AAB;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
            <div style="display: flex; width: 60%; justify-content: center;">
                <input name="preview" class="btn-grey" value="Preview" style="flex-basis: 120px; width: 120px; height: 35px;max-width: 120px; max-height: 35px; margin : 5px 5px 5px 5px " title="preview"/>
                <input name="load" class="btn-grey" type="submit" value="Load " style="width: 120px; height: 35px;max-width: 120px; max-height: 35px;margin : 5px 5px 5px 5px "/>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**hi try this:**

```
.btn-grey{
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```